# Universal introduction with a limited vocabulary

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I understand (I think) how to apply Universal Introduction in general, but am uncertain how to use it with a specified limited vocabulary.

For example, given a language with a finite set of object constants, $\{a,b,c\}$ from the premises

$$\Pi =\{p(a),p(b),p(c)\}$$

I can use Universal Introduction to conclude things like

$$\Pi \vdash\forall x.p(a)$$

or

$$\Pi \vdash\forall c.p(c)$$

but I don't see how I can use these premises to get

$$\Pi \vdash\forall x.p(x)$$

even though it is clearly the case (I think) that

$$\Pi \models\forall x.p(x)$$

Can I use using (finite) Herbrand semantics to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Pi \not\vDash \forall x. p(x)$, and hence $\Pi \not\vdash \forall x. p(x)$. The problem is that you could have objects in your domain which aren't named. Here's a model which satisfies $\Pi$, but doesn't satisfy $\forall x. p(x)$: Let the domain consist of 5 objects, and let 4 of those objects be $p$-objects (i.e. put 4 objects into the extension of $p$). Give the names $a,b,c$ to 3 of those $p$-objects. This will satisfy $\Pi$ but fail to satisfy $\forall x. p(x)$, since we have one lonely non-$p$ object in the domain, i.e. the extension of $p$ is not the entire domain.

Now, if you included in $\Pi$ the extra sentence $\forall x (x = a \vee x = b \vee x = c)$, then we would have $\Pi \vDash \forall x. p(x)$, since this extra sentence guarantees that all of the objects are named by one of the three constants. To show $\Pi + \forall x (x = a \vee x = b \vee x = c) \vdash \forall x. p(x)$, you could use identity rules from your deduction system.

---

If you're using (finite) Herbrand semantics, then your deduction system should have some sort of "domain closure rule" which allows you to deduce $\forall x.p(x)$ given every instance of $p(x)$, which in this case is $\Pi$. See [this webpage from Stanford](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/chapters/chapter_07.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm probably not asking the question quite right. I'm assuming that all I've got is Herbrand, and I don't have things that look like "$x=a$". Is there a way, in Herbrand, to accomplish this in the case where the "names" and the objects correspond, i.e. $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all that there is in the universe, and I know that all of them are $p$ objects? Isn't $\forall x.p(x)$ entailed in that case?

Comment: Ah, I see. The fact that you're using Herbrand semantics would have been good to know, as it works very differently from the FOL semantics. I've edited the original answer.

Comment: Thanks. This qualifies as my most embarrassing question (among many). That's *exactly* the text I'm using, and I somehow missed Domain Closure (we've never actually had occasion to use it; that's my excuse, anyway).